# Want Work Checked on Long Math Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I've got a long math problem that I'm not sure I've done my work correctly on, can someone tell me I did everything right or point out my mistakes?

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)dp^k}{s\sqrt{1-\dfrac{r}{r+dp^k}}}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)dp^k}{s\sqrt{1-\dfrac{r}{r+dp^k}}}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)dp^k}{s\sqrt{\dfrac{r+dp^k}{r+dp^k}-\dfrac{r}{r+dp^k}}}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)dp^k}{s\sqrt{\dfrac{dp^k}{r+dp^k}}}$$
If $\frac{r}{dp^k}$ is sufficently large(the larger, the better the approximation), then the bottom $dp^k$ can effectively be removed. This is where this becomes an approximation.
$$\approx \lim_{p\rightarrow1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)dp^k}{s\sqrt{\dfrac{dp^k}{r}}}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{(1-p)\sqrt{dr}(\sqrt{p^0}+\sqrt{p^1}+\sqrt{p^2}\dots)}{s}$$
Summing $\sqrt{p^0}+\sqrt{p^1}+\sqrt{p^2}\dots=S$
$$\sqrt{p^0}+\sqrt{p^1}+\sqrt{p^2}\dots=S$$
$$\qquad-\sqrt{p^1}-\sqrt{p^2}\dots=-\sqrt{p}S$$
$$1=(1-\sqrt{p})S$$
$$S=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{p}}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{(1-p)\sqrt{dr}\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{p}}}{s}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{(1-p)\sqrt{dr}}{s(1-\sqrt{p})}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{(1-p)(1+\sqrt{p})\sqrt{dr}}{s(1-\sqrt{p})(1+\sqrt{p})}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{(1-p)(1+\sqrt{p})\sqrt{dr}}{s(1-p)}$$
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{(1+\sqrt{p})\sqrt{dr}}{s}$$
$$\frac{(1+1)\sqrt{dr}}{s}$$
$$\frac{2\sqrt{dr}}{s}$$

Note:There is a reason I developed this problem and wrote all of the variables. I'm not just doing it entirely for fun.